# Popup modal to not be jumpy

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, popup, conditional-statements

I created a popup modal with Jquery and I have three questions about it.

1. Right now I have the popup to close on click with the button but I also want it to close when clicking outside of the popup.
2. When the user close the popup in the middle of the page, I want the page to stay where it is and not jump back to the top.
3. Once the user click close to the popup, it won't appear again. I'm guessing I might need to write another condition statement.

Do you guys have any hint or documentation I can look over? So sorry for asking a lot of questions. I am still new to web development.

Thank you and below are my code.

```
    $(document).scroll(function(){
    var a = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (a > 500) {
        $("#mc_embed_signup").fadeIn();
    } else 

    $(".popup-close").click(function(e){
            closeSPopup();
        });
});

function closeSPopup(){
    $("#mc_embed_signup").fadeTo(0);
}
```

Comment: create a minimal example to get an answer no one can guess why your modal is jumpy without seeing it jumping **¯\\_(ツ)_/¯**

Comment: well that is all I have for the jquery popup back the rest are html and css for the popup and I thought it wasn't necessary to show css and html portion of it.

Answer (score 0):

What about 0 JS and all the features you need?
Use basically `checkboxes` and `label` elements.

```css
.modalToggler, 
.modalOuter,
.modal {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.modalToggler:checked + .modalOuter,
.modalToggler:checked + .modalOuter + .modal{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
.modalOuter {
  position: fixed;
  top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0; 
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
.modal {
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 24px;
  background: #fff;
  max-width: 300px;  /* as needed */
}
.modalClose {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  top: 0; right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- MY MODALS -->

<input id="modal1" class="modalToggler" type="checkbox">
<label for="modal1" class="modalOuter"></label>
<div class="modal">
  <label for="modal1" class="modalClose">&#x2716;</label>
  Hello, World
</div>

<input id="modal2" class="modalToggler" type="checkbox">
<label for="modal2" class="modalOuter"></label>
<div class="modal">
  <label for="modal2" class="modalClose">&#x2716;</label>
  How cool is that?
</div>

<!-- !MY MODALS -->


<label for="modal1"><a>SHOW-MODAL1</a></label>

<label for="modal2"><a>SHOW-MODAL2</a></label>
```

## JS for the scroll!

Now let's add the scrolling part by just adding a tiny bit of jQuery, nothing more:

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function(){
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (st > 500) {
        $("#modal1").attr("checked", true);
    }
});
```

```css
.modalToggler, 
.modalOuter,
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.modalToggler:checked + .modalOuter,
.modalToggler:checked + .modalOuter + .modal{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
.modalOuter {
  top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0; 
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
.modal {
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 24px;
  background: #fff;
  max-width: 300px;  /* as needed */
}
.modalClose {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  top: 0; right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- MY MODALS -->

<input id="modal1" class="modalToggler" type="checkbox">
<label for="modal1" class="modalOuter"></label>
<div class="modal">
  <label for="modal1" class="modalClose">&#x2716;</label>
  <h3>Get 30%</h3>
  <p>On every book from our shelf</p>
  <p><button>APPLY NOW!</button></p>
</div>

<!-- !MY MODALS -->

<div style="border:4px dashed #000; height: 300vh"> <!--Demo sytles! Don't ever inline CSS-->
   <label for="modal1"><a>SHOW-MODAL1</a></label>
   
   <p>Scroll down.......</p>
</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is super cool Roko but it for an email subscribe so I can have the popup to appear on click, it need to appear on scrolling but I will look through your code and see if there is anything I can pick apart. Thank you.

Comment: @skyeyl I'll show you now an example with scroll with just a bit of JS with the same above's markup and CSS

Comment: This is awesome, thank you so much. I am gonna implement my html with it and see if it work. I appreciate it.